# JQM - How to detect if item is shown on screen

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm using JQuery mobile and I would like to raise an event when the listview is scrolled and a specific item is shown on screen.

Is there an  event for this?! what are my options?!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there are no events in jQM to do this, but you could combine ideas from some other solutions on StackOverflow to do this.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/jquery-check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling) provides some code to determine if an item is visible, i.e.:

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom >= docViewTop) && (elemTop <= docViewBottom)
      && (elemBottom <= docViewBottom) &&  (elemTop >= docViewTop) );
}
```

You can combine this with the `scrollstop` event. Say you are monitoring a `<li>` item defined as

```
 <li id="myiditem">
      <a href="bmw.html">I'm being watched!!</a>
 </li>
```

Then in `$(document).ready` you can do

```
var watchitem;
$(document).ready(function(){
    watchitem = document.getElementById ('myiditem');  
    /* Bind to scroll event */
    $(window).bind('scrollstop', function () {
        if (isScrolledIntoView( watchitem )) {
            alert('monitored li item was scrolled into view');
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sZzv5/) example.